# Classifying Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Determine up to similarity all $3 \times 3$ complex matrices $A$ such that $A^4 + 2A^3 + A^2 = 0$ and $A^2 + A \neq 0$. Give the characteristic and minimal polynomial of each matrix.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. First, it's clear that the minimal polynomial of any matrix which satisfies these conditions must divide,
\begin{align*}
p(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 = 0
\end{align*}

and one can factor this into $x^2(x+1)(x+1)$. Also, I am aware that similar matrices share the same characteristic/minimal polynomials. There may also, perhaps, be a connection to Jordan Canonical Form. What I am not sure about is, how can we find the characteristic polynomial, how exactly does the condition $A^2 + A \neq 0$ factor into this, and how do I know when I've found all of the matrices.

Comment: I don't have the solution, but since $A(A+1)\ne0$, the minimal polynomial cannot be a divisor of $x(x+1)$. There are now very few possible options for the minimal polynomial.

Comment: And yes, from that point I would probably list the possible cases of Jordan normal forms.

Comment: Ah I see, so the only valid minimal polynomials would be $x^2$, $x^2(x+1)$,$x(x+1)^2$, or $x^2(x+1)^2$. How does the characteristic polynomial come into play here?

Comment: You can find the characteristic polynomial from the Jordan normal form. You don't need it to list the matrices.

Comment: Are you familiar with Jordan's canonical form? If you are, then suppose $J$ is the Jordan's canonical form of $A$, with $J=PAP^{-1}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
&A^4 + 2A^3 + A^2 = 0 &\\
\iff & P(A^4 + 2A^3 + A^2 )P^{-1}= 0 & (\text{since $P0P^{-1}=0$})\\
\iff & J^4 + 2J^3 + J^2 = 0 & (\text{since $PA^nP^{-1}=PAP^{-1}PAP^{-1}\cdots PAP^{-1}=J^n$})
\end{align*}
The same argument gives $J^2+J\ne 0$.

Comment: The rest is (lengthy but easy) case work: If $A$ has three eigenvalues, then $J$ must be $\mathtt{diag}\{\lambda,\mu, \omega\}$. If $A$ has two, then
\begin{equation*}
J=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 &  \\ 
& \lambda &  \\ 
&  & \mu
\end{pmatrix} \text{ or } \mathtt{diag}\{\lambda,\lambda,\mu\}.
\end{equation*}  
If $A$ has one, then there are three cases: "$1+1+1$, $2+1$, $3$" (corresponding to the size of each Jordan block). 
Please work through these six situations :).

Comment: So the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue tells us how many times it appears on the diagonal and the geometric tells us how many blocks they are in? By your example $\lambda$ has algebraic multiplicity 2 and geometric multiplicity 1 and $\mu$ has both multiplicities equal to 1?

Comment: @Important_man74 "the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue tells us how many times it appears on the diagonal and the geometric tells us how many blocks they are in" is correct.

Comment: In
\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 &  \\  & \lambda &  \\  &  & \mu \end{pmatrix},\end{equation}
$\lambda$ has geometric multiplicity $1$, algebraic multiplicity $2$, while $\mu$ has both multipllicity $1$. As for $\mathtt{diag}\{\lambda,\lambda,\mu\}$, $\lambda $ has both multiplicity $2$, and $\mu$ has both multiplicity $1$. ($\mathtt{diag}\{\lambda,\lambda,\mu\}$ has three Jordan blocks $\{\lambda\},\{\lambda\},\{\mu\}$.)

Comment: @Asigan sorry for the late response but i am still a bit confused. Is it true that all of the matrices here share the characteristic polynomial $x^2(x+1)^2$? I'm not really sure where each of the 6 cases you mention arise from. Also, I am not quite sure about my comment above about the possible valid minimal polynomials. Finally, isn't it only possible that a matrix which satisfies these relations can only have 1 or 0 as an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Important_man74 Ok, I have written a complete answer to show how the Jordan form is applied to solve such kind of problem. As for your other questions, (1) Since $A$ is of size $3\times 3$, it must have characteristic polynomial of degree $3$, and therefore can never be $x^2(x+1)^2$. (2) I confess in my previous comment, my cases are redundant. It can be reduced to three cases. (3) Yes, $A$ can not admit eigenvalues other than $0$ and (I think rather than $1$ you mean) $-1$. In fact in my answer I suppose the eigenvalues are unknown and then show they are $-1$ or $0$.

Comment: In my answer, an alternative approach is one by one check (for example in case two) whether $(\lambda,\mu)=(-1,-1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,-1)$, $(0,0)$ are solutions, and the same for other two cases. But I think that is even more complicated than directly solve them from equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer complete I first repeat some of my comment.
Suppose $J$ is the Jordan's canonical form of $A$, with $J=PAP^{-1}$.
Then we have
\begin{align*} &A^4 + 2A^3 + A^2 = 0 &\\ \iff & P(A^4 + 2A^3 + A^2 )P^{-1}= 0 & (\text{since $P0P^{-1}=0$})\\ \iff & J^4 + 2J^3 + J^2 = 0 & (\text{since $PA^nP^{-1}=PAP^{-1}PAP^{-1}\cdots PAP^{-1}=J^n$}) \end{align*}
The same argument gives $J^2+J\ne 0$.
So it suffices to determine all the Jordan-canonical form $J$ s.t. $J^4 + 2J^3 + J^2 = 0$, $J^2+J\ne 0$.
There are three cases according to the sizes and numbers Jordan blocks. We are going to check them case by case.

For convinience denote $f(x)=x^4+2x^3+x^2$, $ g(x)=x^2+x $. Note that $f(x_0)=0$ $\implies$ $x_0\in\{0,-1\}$ $\implies$ $g(x_0)=0$.

Case 1: $J$ has Jordan blocks "$1+1+1$". (That is it has three Jordan blocks, each with size one.)

Then $J=\mathtt{diag}\{\lambda,\mu, \omega\}$, where $\lambda,\mu, \omega$ need not be distinct.
Since $J^4 + 2J^3 + J^2 = 0$, we have $f(\lambda)=f(\mu)=f(\omega)=0$.
Therefore $\lambda,\mu, \omega\in\{0,-1\}$.
But this implies $\lambda,\mu, \omega$ are zeros of $g(x)$.
Hence $J^2+J=\mathtt{diag}\{g(\lambda),g(\mu), g(\omega)\}=0$, a contradiction.
Therefore Case 1 is impossible.

Case 2: $J$ has Jordan blocks "$2+1$".

Then
\begin{equation*}
J=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 &  \\  & \lambda &  \\  &  & \mu \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda,\mu$ need not be distinct.
A direct computation gives
\begin{equation*}
J^4 + 2J^3 + J^2 =\begin{pmatrix}
f(\lambda) & 4\lambda^3+6\lambda^3+2\lambda^2 &  \\ 
& f(\lambda) &  \\ 
&  & f(\mu)
\end{pmatrix}. 
\end{equation*}
So we must have $f(\lambda)=f(\mu)=4\lambda^3+6\lambda^3+2\lambda^2=0$.
This gives $\lambda,\mu \in\{-1,0\}$.

Another direct computation gives
\begin{equation*}
J^2+J=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^2+\lambda & 2\lambda+1 &  \\ 
& \lambda^2+\lambda &  \\ 
&  & \mu^2+\mu
\end{pmatrix}. 
\end{equation*}
When $\lambda\in\{0,-1\}$,  $2\lambda+1\ne 0$.
Therefore $J^2+J\ne 0$ whenever $\lambda\in\{0,-1\}$.

Hence case 2 gives four solutions:
\begin{equation*}
J=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 &  \\  & \lambda &  \\  &  & \mu \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda,\mu\in\{0,-1\}$.

Case three: $J$ has Jordan blocks "$3$".
Then
\begin{equation*}
J=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 &  \\ 
& \lambda & 1 \\ 
&  & \lambda
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation*}
A direct proof gives
\begin{equation*}
J^4 + 2J^3 + J^2=\begin{pmatrix}
f(\lambda) & \text{the value here is not important} & 4\lambda^2+3\lambda+1 \\ 
& f(\lambda) & \text{the value here is not important} \\ 
&  & f(\lambda)
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation*}
Since $f(\lambda)$ and $ 4\lambda^2+3\lambda+1 $ can not be zero at the same time, we conclude Case three is impossible.

To sum up there are (up to similarity) four choices for $J$ (and hence for $A$):
\begin{equation*}
J=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 &  \\  & \lambda &  \\  &  & \mu \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda,\mu\in\{0,-1\}$.

Comment: wow thanks a lot for the thorough answer.